# How to insert multiple record without loop in laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, eloquent, query-builder

I have I need to insert multiple record in database . Currently I am inserting with loop which is causing timeout when record is big. Is there any way that we dont use loop?

```
$consignments =   Consignment::select('id')->where('customer_id',$invoice->customer_id)->doesntHave('invoice_charges')->get();
       foreach($consignments as $consignment){
         InvoiceCharge::create(['invoice_id'=>$invoice->id,'object_id'=>$consignment->id,'model'=>'Consignment']);
       }
```

consignment has `hasOne` relation in model

```
public function invoice_charges()
    {
        return $this->hasOne('App\Models\Admin\InvoiceCharge', 'object_id')->where('model', 'Consignment');
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about this:

```
$consignments = Consignment::select('id')->where('customer_id',$invoice->customer_id)->doesntHave('invoice_charges')->get();
       foreach($consignments as $consignment){
         $consignment_data[] = ['invoice_id'=>$invoice->id,'object_id'=>$consignment->id,'model'=>'Consignment'];
       }
InvoiceCharge::insert($consignment_data);
```

In this way you enter with one query rather than loop. Just check if consignment_data array is ok.

Comment: giving this error ```Argument 1 passed to Illuminate\Database\Grammar::parameterize() must be of the type array, string given, called in /var/www/html/coldxlogistics/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Query/Grammars/Grammar.php on line 869
```

Comment: can you dd($consignment_data) before InvoiceCharge::create($consignment_data);

Comment: Your method is correct but need to use insert instead of create

Answer (score 0):

If you want to save time, but can give more memory, you can use `Cursor`,

> Cursor: You will use PHP Generators to search your query items one by one. 1)It takes less time 2) Uses more memory

```
$consignments =   Consignment::select('id')->where('customer_id',$invoice->customer_id)->doesntHave('invoice_charges')->cursor();
       foreach($consignments as $consignment){
         InvoiceCharge::create(['invoice_id'=>$invoice->id,'object_id'=>$consignment->id,'model'=>'Consignment']);
       }
```

You can refer from [here](http://%20https://translate.google.com/translate?hl=en&sl=auto&tl=en&u=http%3A%2F%2Fqiita.com%2Fryo511%2Fitems%2Febcd1c1b2ad5addc5c9d)